# why text field results returned as html document in zend lucene?

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, lucene

I am using zend lucene search engine, I have a text field named title, its value printed in the search results page as a full structured html document, here is my code:

adding the field in the creation:

```
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('title',CHtml::encode($post->title), 'utf-8'));
```

printing the field in the search results page:

```
<?php  echo $query->highlightMatches(CHtml::encode($result->title)); ?>
```

how its displayed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head><body>بالصور: كهوف مضيئة <script type="text/javascript" src="/~arraqeeb/js/news.ticker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/~arraqeeb/js/imgs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/~arraqeeb/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

my problem that i don't these html tags to appear, because they are printed inside the body of my html page, so i am expecting the result to be only the title text as follow:

```
بالصور: كهوف مضيئة
```

sorry for my bad explanation of the problem, I am newbie to lucene, I hope you have a solution for this problem

Comment: While adding the field in Lucene doc what is the value of `$post->title`? Is this also containing HTML tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution to your problem could be [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags) while outputting your data.

```
<?php echo strip_tags($query->highlightMatches(CHtml::encode($result->title))); ?>
```